# Why is Software Update offering RC version of Command Line Tools for Xcode and how do I prevent this in the future?

Tags: xcode, developer-program

As of yesterday, I'm seeing a software update notification for Command Line Tools for Xcode version 13.4. I have Xcode and the Command Line Tools for Xcode installed on my machine, but am using Xcode Version 13.3.1. I originally installed Xcode through the Mac App Store.

[image: Screenshot of Software Update offering Release Candidate version of Command Line Tools for Xcode version 13.4]

However, Xcode 13.4 (and its Command Line Tools) is only currently out as a Release Candidate (RC) as shown here: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

[image: Screenshot of Apple's "More" page on the Apple Developer site's Download section.]

Is it possible I've put myself into a beta/RC channel accidentally? Is there some way to prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have exactly the same experience. My interpretation is that Apple have fully released version 13.4 Command Line Tools for Xcode. After installation, in System Information the version is given as 13.4 with no mention of beta or RC.

So, don't worry, Apple is asking you to install what is now the current version of Command Line Tools.

Note, Command Line Tools is (or can be) a separate install to Xcode and is updated via the Software Update mechanism. I expect we will soon be offered Xcode 13.4 via the App Store.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you installed homebrew ([https://brew.sh](https://brew.sh/))?

Comment: I do have Homebrew installed, but I installed the Xcode Command Line Tools along with Xcode before doing so. I installed Xcode from the App Store, and did not opt into any beta/RC versions of Xcode. Can you expand on why you think Homebrew might put me in some beta/RC channel for Software Updates related to Xcode?

Comment: @GavinAnderegg See my 'answer'. I don't believe you have been put into the beta channel.